# Jenkins upgrade to 2.32.3 issue?

Tags: jenkins

Recently i have upgraded Jenkins from v1.596.2 to 2.32.3(LTS). But after upgradation i am getting following error but no clear how to rectify it.

=========================================================================
Tomcat Deploy v1.0.16

## You must update Jenkins from v2.32.3 to v3.0.0 or later to run this plugin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the "Tomcat Deploy" plugin from? It doesn't appear to be a plugin offered by default in Jenkins.

Comment: I don not  know from where it coming? i don't even have this plugin  entry in installed plugins

Comment: If the plugin can't be loaded by Jenkins, I guess it might not appear in the plugin list. You can delete the tomcat-deploy (or whatever) file and directory in `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` on the master machine if you don't need the plugin.

Comment: Ok..Apart from this some of plugins are got hanged like below image. is this means plugin is not supported?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the image of the Ant plugin. What error messages are you seeing? Can you post the errors from the [Jenkins log](https://jenkins.io/redirect/find-jenkins-logs/) if there are any?

Comment: I am unable to uninstall plugin, when i am clicking its saying there are more dependent plugins...Is this expected behavior in new core.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138116/discussion-between-anil-yadav-and-christopher-orr).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I had the same problem (but with others plugins).
To fix that:

1. Put Jenkins in "Prepare for Shutdown" mode and shutdown it
2. On the server HDD go to `JENKINS_HOME/plugins` and delete (or move elsewhere) the folder and `hpi` file corresponding to plugin which produce warnings. (The name of file/folder can be a little bit different than the plugin name displayed in Jenkins)
3. Restart Jenkins. Warning should be deleted